# js: handling dynamic json generation from fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a dynamically generated JSON with dynamic keys and values and somehow went down the wrong way. Each field in the `<form>` has a `data-key` attribute set, so the parser knows the key name:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="..." data-key="name" value="chicken">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="..." data-key="price" value="4.10">
```

I get all products in the this shape:

```
[
    {
        "number": 4957,
        "data": {
            "name": "chicken",
            "price": 9
        }
    },...
]
```

and I try to generate a new one by:

```
let form = document.querySelector('#productForm');
let number = document.querySelector('#productLabel').getAttribute("prodid");
keys = Object.keys(products[0].data); // ["name", "price"]
let d = {}
    
    keys.forEach(function ( key ) {
        for ( let fe = 0; fe < form.elements.length; fe++ ) {
            if ( form.elements[fe].getAttribute("data-key") === key ) {
                d[key] = form.elements[fe].value;
            };
        };
    });
    let return_json = {"number": number, "data": d};
```

but in the devtools it looks like this:

[image]

why is `d[key]` resulting in `data[name]: chicken` and not in `{..., data: {"name": chicken...}}`

**EDIT**: someone asked for the request:

```
$.ajax({ url: "api/products/",
         type: "PUT",
         data: return_json,
         headers: { 'X-CSRFTOKEN': csrf_token },
         success: function () { ... },
         error: function ( request, status, error ) { ... }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your dev tools aren't lying to you? What if you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(return_json));`?

Comment: this outputs `{"number":"4957","data":{"name":"chicken","price":"4"}}`. why would it show like this in devtools/network/request?

Comment: How are you making the request?

Comment: have you tried to explicitly set the datatype to JSON in your ajax call?

Comment: yes, same outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you're using jQuery's form-data serialization, which does exactly that (to be compatible with PHP's defaults).

You will need to stringify the data to JSON yourself and set the correct content-type header:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "api/products/",
  type: "PUT",
  data: JSON.stringify(return_json),
  headers: { "X-CSRFTOKEN": csrf_token, "Content-type": "application/json" },
  // ...
});
```